# I would like to reward bounty but question is closed, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, support

After editing of [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/is-there-a-concept-of-qualification-examination-in-u-s-ph-d-programs-and-how-d?noredirect=1#comment147889_62176) 
by Jakebeal, to clarify content, question still remains closed. I cannot reward any bouty. What is a process for opening again question?

Comment: If you believe it's sufficiently clear now, you can cast a reopen vote (which pushes it into the review queue), and then wait for others to vote on it.

Comment: Update: it's gone through the review queue and 3 users voted to leave closed. It can still get reopen votes by users who come across it in other ways, but it's not in the queue anymore. See [review details](http://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/32937).

Comment: I think that Jakebeal clarified question 100%, I dont understand why people voted to remain closed?

Comment: @SSimon Personally, I'm one of your reopen votes, so I can't explain why others left it closed.  If you want to understand and/or argue for reopening, you are welcome to do so in a new Meta question.

Comment: I know, @jakebeal I saw you vote for reopen, but now I am not sure how to address this question. as general one or concrete one? Should I mention other reviewers and ask for their reason to still block question?